# How to set an dynamic array for AppService appsettings in ARM template

Tags: yaml, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I want to set appsettings for appservice as array(name-value) in the yml overrideparameters as below

[image: yml file]

How do i set this in the Arm template? I have tried a failed attempt something like below

[image: arm template]

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no standard form to do. Need to use `array` inside of appsettings & `union` to merge a dynamic value in a json.

By this way we can achieve to add app service application settings in a ARM Template.

[image]

We can access the above appsetting key and values following way.

[image]

Refer [here](https://kalcik.net/2019/11/21/merge-azure-app-service-app-settings-in-arm-template/)

Comment: What i am looking for is to avoid any values or key with the arm template and instead send array from the yml dynamically.